# Get/set issue getting with join query in entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to fill a data in `public IList<Order> OrderList { get; set; }` with join 2 table. for that i have written a code in dbEntities below

```
using (var db = new dbEntities())
{
     OrderList  = (from row in db.Orders
                 join rowjoin in db.Users on row.UserId equals rowjoin.Id
                 orderby row.OrderNumber
                 select new { row.Id, row.UserId, row.TechnicianId, row.OrderNumber, row.ModelName,
                 row.ServiceName,row.IconUrl,row.Cost,row.Position, row.Status, rowjoin.FirstName ,
                 rowjoin.LastName, rowjoin.MobileNumber, rowjoin.Email,rowjoin.City, rowjoin.Address}).ToList();
}
```

its giving an error 2:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IList<Mobileappy.Order>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How do i fix it?

Comment: How is this related to MVC and razor ?

Comment: dbEntities code is did in model class which is helping to bind a data in table its not working with join query only with single table it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OrderList property needs to be a new type that can hold combination of both User and Order(like ViewModel). You can create properties for newly created type in two ways.
1. Create all required properties(User's properties + Order's proeperties) for newly created viewmodel and assign values thru the linq query.

```
public class OrderUserVM
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    ...
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    ...
}
 public IList<OrderUserVM> OrderList { get; set; }
 OrderList = (from row in db.Orders
                         join rowjoin in db.Users on row.UserId equals rowjoin.Id
                         orderby row.OrderNumber
                         select new OrderUserVM
                         {
                             OrderNumber = row.OrderNumber,
                             ...
                             FirstName = rowjoin.FirstName,
                             ....
                         }).ToList();
```

OR
2. Create only two properties of type 'User'  and 'Order' for newly created viewmodel and assign values thru the linq query.

```
public class OrderUserVM
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
public IList<OrderUserVM> OrderList { get; set; }
OrderList = (from row in db.Orders
                         join rowjoin in db.Users on row.UserId equals rowjoin.Id
                         orderby row.OrderNumber
                         select new OrderUserVM
                         {
                             Order = row,
                             User = rowjoin,

                         }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query is not returning Order objects but an anonymous type.
If you want to get a `List<Order>` you must `select row` instead of `select new {...}`.

Comment: I did it before like this select row).ToList(); and its returning Order without any issue but i want to returning Users too for display some filed from it in datatable

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a new Type (OrderUser) with the info of both the Order and the User. Then, instead of use `select new {...}` you must use `select new OrderUser(){ UserName = rowjoin.FirstName, OrderId = row.Id, ... }`. Change `public IList<Order> OrderList { get; set; }` by `public IList<OrderUser> OrderList { get; set; }`

Comment: exactly where i need to declare OrderUser i didn't get you exactly